# NOT NULL constraint asking for a default value

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

Adding a new column to my database with a NOT NULL constraint but Redshift is alerting me that I should define a default value. I thought the point of NOT NULL was to force a definition?

```
ALTER TABLE users add column
  name varchar(255) NOT NULL
;
```

Results in:

```
[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN defined as NOT NULL must have a non-null default expression;
```

Is there a way to enforce a column must not be null?

Comment: What value should the existing rows in the database have for the new column? They can't be null, so you have to add a default to the new row.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`NOT NULL` is the correct way to ensure a column contains a value.
However, because your table already exists, the rows which are already in it won't have a value for your new `name` column, therefore they would breach the `NOT NULL` constraint.

By specifying a default value, you are ensuring that any existing rows are assigned that value, thereby complying with your `NOT NULL` constraint.

Comment: While tinkering around I discovered I can create a new table with NOT NULL constraints on the rows. Your answer makes sense, if a table already exists you cannot retroactively add a NOT NULL constraint because there may be NULL values. It's a meta constraint on your table when they ask for a default value.

Comment: Exactly. When you're crating the table, you can add (or omit) whatever constraints you like, because there is no data to constrain.

Comment: PostgreSQL will not add default values to existing null fields, you have to update those records manually

Answer (score 6):

If the column is `NOT NULL`, it has to have a value, right?

Why not add: `DEFAULT default_expr`

Comment: One does not always want a default value.

Comment: How would you comply with the NOT NULL constraint, then? Downvote was totally unecessary.

Comment: What I would do is add the column without the NOT NULL constraint, populate the column with the appropriate values, then alter the column to add the NOT NULL constraint (assuming the column should be NOT NULL).

Comment: See Colonel Thirty Two's answer above.